# Can a .eth domain from ENS be used for a website?

Tags: ens

I recently registered a .eth domain through the Ethereum Name Service. Is it possible to use this domain for a website? Or is it just an alias for an ethereum address (and other metadata)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but AFAIK not all the browsers resolve `.eth` domains automatically, you'll need a gateway.

About your question, it's is possible to link a website with a ENS domain if you link the web content with your `.eth` domain. You can do it with IPFS or Swarm but in this case I'm going to focus on [Swarm](https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), so:

**About Swarm**

From the [Swarm docs](https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/ens.html#ethereum-name-system-ens):

> By registering a name and setting it to resolve to the content hash of
>   the root manifest of your site, users can access your site via a URL
>   such as `bzz://theswarm.eth/`.
>
> Currently The bzz scheme is not supported in major browsers such as
>   Chrome, Firefox or Safari. If you want to access the bzz scheme
>   through these browsers, currently you have to either use an HTTP
>   gateway, such as https://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/theswarm.eth/ or use
>   a browser which supports the bzz scheme, such as Mist
>   https://github.com/ethereum/mist.

**About ENS**

From the [ENS docs](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/publicresolver#get-content-hash):

> `contenthash` is used to store IPFS and Swarm content hashes, which
>   permit resolving ENS addresses to distributed content (eg, websites)
>   hosted on these distributed networks.

- With Geth:

Using the function [`setContenthash`](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/publicresolver#set-content-hash):

```
function setContenthash(bytes32 node, bytes calldata hash) external;
```

Where:

```
node: namehash("yourdomain.eth") if you do it manually with a client like Geth or yourdomain.eth if you use ENS manager.
hash: e.g. the Swarm or IPFS hash of the content you’re referring
```

Once you own the `eth` domain and doing some steps like [setting the resolver](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/ens#set-resolver):

```
publicResolver.setContenthash(namehash("yourdomain.eth"), "hashOfYourContent", {from: eth.coinbase})
```

- With ENS Manager (used Rinkeby testnet):

[image]

Introduce your IPFS (or Swarm) hash and you will see the following:

[image]

**IPFS**

I've found the following tutorial that will illustrate more easily how to do what you ask with IPFS.

[Tutorial about hosting a Dapp using IPFS and ENS](https://medium.com/the-ethereum-name-service/how-to-host-your-dapp-with-ipfs-ens-and-access-it-via-ethdns-c96046059d87)

**Swarm**

Then you can use the Swarm gateway and browse to your web like that:

https://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/yourdomain.eth/

You can try (probably gives error but if you reload it will work):

https://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/theswarm.eth/

[image]

For your interest, you can test all the process using `.test` ENS names in a testnet like Ropsten or Rinkeby to see how it works. You can read more about [here](https://docs.ens.domains/ens-deployments).

Comment: Answer updated to provide more information and organize it.

Comment: Thanks! This isn't exactly what I wanted in terms of using an ETH domain like a regular web domain. But it's highly relevant, very interesting, and moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

No not the traditional way. It gives (sub)domain names to ETH addresses.

https://medium.com/@eric.conner/the-ultimate-guide-to-ens-names-aa541586067a
https://docs.ens.domains/

Comment: I appreciate your point, but it's also possible to associate metadata with the address/subdomain. This seems to open many possibilities including something like a DNS record.